# Correct usage (words ending -es)

Tags: grammar

The new businesses' venture.

Does this example require an apostrophe with businesses.

What would be multiple businesses if this is just one businesses' venture. (Would you have to say: the group of businesses venture, for instance?)

Answer (score 2):

There's no special rule.

If it's singular you add *'s* to make the possessive: *the new business's venture*.

If it's a regular plural (in *-s* or *-es*) you add the apostrophe to make it possessive: *the new businesses' venture*.

Why we do this is a historical accident. *Business's*, *businesses* and *businesses'* all sound identical, and we manage perfectly well in speech with this potential ambiguity; but custom decrees that when we write them down we have to work out whether we mean singular possessive, plural, or plural possessive.